# How to use serializer field and make response of the data from the choice field in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to use serializer field in DRF

`models.py`

```
class User(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, unique=True)
birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)

gender_choice = [
    ('male','male'),
    ('female','female')

]
gender = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=gender_choice, default='male', null=True)
```

**the rest ans is in the below**

Answer (score 0):

`serializers.py`

```
class UserRegSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    show_me = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_show_me') #the extra serializer field

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'birthdate', 'gender')

    def get_show_me(self, showmeobj): #this fuction returns the data

        gender = getattr(showmeobj, 'gender')
        if gender == 'male':
            return 'Queen' #if user's gender is male (opposite gender)
        else:
            return 'King' #if user's gender is female (opposite gender)
```

`view.py`

```
class UserCreateAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
serializer_class = UserRegSerializer
queryset = User.objects.all()

def post(self, request):
    first_name = request.data.get('first_name', False)
    birthdate = request.data.get('birthdate', False)
    gender = request.data.get('gender', False)

    serializer = UserRegSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({
            'status': True, 
            'message': 'Register User Successfully',
            'data': serializer.data, 

        }, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    else :  
        return Response({
            'status': False,
            'message': 'Error! something went wrong',
            }, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

hope this answer will help you. changes accepted:)